# Undefined is not a function when navigating to login page

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have been trying to make an react native app version for a website which I implemented using React. I got the website to work, and I am now trying to build an app for the same, trying to use pretty much the same functions and architecture as the web version.

The home page is displayed correctly, and the home page contains a link to navigate to the login page. However when I do navigate to that page, an error is thrown "Undefined is not a function". I understand what the error means, but I can't seem to resolve it. It should have worked given that I implemented it looking at the web version.

Any help would be appreciated.

App.js

```
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import LoginForm from "./src/screens/LoginForm";
import LogoutScreen from "./src/screens/LogoutScreen";
import BoardAdmin from "./src/screens/BoardAdmin";
import BoardStudent from "./src/screens/BoardStudent";
import Home from "./src/screens/Home";
import CustomDrawerContent from "./src/DrawerContent";
import ResolveAuthScreen from "./src/screens/ResolveAuthScreen";
import { Provider as AuthProvider } from "./src/context/AuthContext";

const loginFlow = createStackNavigator({
  Home: Home,
  Login: LoginForm
})

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function myDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={<Home />}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name="BoardAdmin" component={<BoardAdmin />}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name="BoardStudent" component={<BoardStudent />} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Logout" component={<LogoutScreen />}/>
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  )
}

const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  resolve: ResolveAuthScreen,
  loginFlow: loginFlow,
  drawer: myDrawer
})

const App = createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator);

export default () => {
  return <AuthProvider>
    <App />
  </AuthProvider>
}
```

AuthContext.js

```
import createDataContext from "./createDataContext";
    import { login, getCurrentUser, logout, registerStudent } from "../api/auth_services";
    
    const authReducer = (state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'add_error':
                return {...state, errorMessage: (action.payload.response &&
                    action.payload.response.data &&
                    action.payload.response.data.message) ||
                  action.payload.message ||
                  action.payload.toString()
                }
            case 'signout' :
                return {...state, currentUser: null, isAdmin: false, isStudent: false};
            case 'signin':
                newState = {...state}
                if (action.payload){
                    newState = {...state, currentUser: action.payload}
                    if (action.payload && action.payload.user && action.payload.user.roles && action.payload.user.roles[0] && action.payload.user.roles[0].name && action.payload.user.roles[0].name === "ADMIN"){
                        newState = {...state, isAdmin: true}
                    }
                    else if (action.payload && action.payload.user && action.payload.user.roles && action.payload.user.roles[0] && action.payload.user.roles[0].name && action.payload.user.roles[0].name === "STUDENT"){
                        newState = {...state, isStudent: true}
                    }
                }
                return newState;
            default :
                return state;
        }
    }
    
    //function to get token from async storage and signin if required
    const tryLocalSignin = (dispatch) => {
        return () => {
            const user = getCurrentUser();
            
            if (user){
                dispatch({type : 'signin', payload: user});
            }
        }
    };
    
    const signupStudent = (dispatch) => {
        return (username, password, studentName, email, phone) => {
            try {
                registerStudent(username, password, studentName, email, phone);
            }catch (err){
                dispatch({type: 'add_error', payload: err})
            }
        };
    };
    
    const signupAdmin = (dispatch) => {
        return (username, password) => {
            try {
                registerAdmin(username, password);
            }catch (err){
                dispatch({type: 'add_error', payload: err})
            }
        }
    }
    
    const signin = (dispatch) => {
        return (username, password) => {
            try {
                const response = login(username, password);
                dispatch({type : 'signin', payload: response});
            }catch (err){
                dispatch({type: 'add_error', payload: 'Invalid username or password'})
            }
        };
    };
    
    const signout = (dispatch) => {
        return () => {
            logout();
            dispatch({type: 'signout'});
        };
    };
    
    export const {Provider, Context} = createDataContext(
        authReducer, 
        {signin, signupStudent, signupAdmin, signout, tryLocalSignin}, 
        {currentUser: null, isAdmin: false, isStudent: false, errorMessage: ""}
    );
```

loginValidator.js

```
    import { useState } from "react";
    import { stringValidator } from "./validators";
    
    const touchErrors = errors => {
        return Object.entries(errors).reduce((acc, [field, fieldError]) => {
          acc[field] = {
            ...fieldError,
            dirty: true,
          };
          return acc;
        }, {});
    };
    
    export const useLoginFormValidator = form => {
      const [errors, setErrors] = useState({
        username: {
          dirty: false,
          error: false,
          message: "",
        },
        password: {
          dirty: false,
          error: false,
          message: "",
        }
      });
    
      const validateForm = ({ form, field, errors, forceTouchErrors = false}) => {
        let isValid = true;
    
        // Create a deep copy of the errors
        var nextErrors = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(errors));
    
        // Force validate all the fields
        if (forceTouchErrors) {
          nextErrors = touchErrors(errors);
        }
    
        const { username, password } = form;
    
        if (nextErrors.username.dirty && (field ? field === "username" : true)) {
          const message = stringValidator(username, form);
          nextErrors.username.error = !!message;
          nextErrors.username.message = message;
          if (!!message) isValid = false;
        }
    
        if (nextErrors.password.dirty && (field ? field === "password" : true)) {
          const passwordMessage = stringValidator(password, form);
          nextErrors.password.error = !!passwordMessage;
          nextErrors.password.message = passwordMessage;
          if (!!passwordMessage) isValid = false;
        }
    
        setErrors(nextErrors);
    
        return {
          isValid,
          errors: nextErrors,
        };
      };
    
      return {
        errors, validateForm
      };
    };
```

LoginForm.js

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
    import useLoginFormValidator from "../validators/loginValidator";
    import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
    import {Text, Button, Input, Card, Image} from 'react-native-elements';
    import Spacer from "../reusables/Spacer";
    import { Context as AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";
    
    const LoginForm = ({navigation}) => {
    
      const {state, signin} = useContext(AuthContext); 
    
        const [form, setForm] = useState({
          username: "",
          password: ""
        }); 
    
        const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    
      const {errors, validateForm} = useLoginFormValidator(form);
    
      const onUpdateField = e => {
        const nextFormState = {
          ...form,
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        };
        setForm(nextFormState);
      };
    
      const onSubmitForm = e => {
        setMessage("")    
        const { isValid } = validateForm({form, errors, forceTouchErrors : true});
        if (!isValid) return;
    
        signin(username, password);
        if (state.isAdmin){
          navigation.navigate("BoardAdmin");
        }else if (state.isStudent){
          navigation.navigate("BoardStudent");
        }
        setMessage(state.errorMessage)
      };
    
      return (<Card>
        <View style={styles.card_container}>
            <Image source="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" alt="profile-img" style={styles.profile_img_card} />
            <View>
                <Spacer>
                    <Input label = "Username" value = {form.username} onChangeText={onUpdateField} autoCapitalize="none" autoCorrect = {false}/>
                    {errors.username.dirty && errors.username.error ? (
                                <Text style={styles.errorMessage}>{errors.username.message}</Text>
                                ) : null}
                </Spacer>
                <Spacer>
                    <Input secureTextEntry label = "Password" value = {form.password} onChangeText = {onUpdateField} autoCapitalize="none" autoCorrect = {false}/>
                    {errors.username.dirty && errors.username.error ? (
                                <Text style={styles.errorMessage}>{errors.username.message}</Text>
                                ) : null}
                </Spacer>
                <Button title="Login" onPress={onSubmitForm}/>
                    
                {message ? 
                      <View style={styles.errorMessage}>{message}</View>
                    : null}
            </View>
        </View>
        
      </Card>)
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        card_container : {
            maxWidth: 350,
            padding: 40
        },
        card: {
            backgroundColor: "gray",
            padding: 25, 
            margin: 25,
            marginTop: 50,
            borderRadius: 2,
        },
        profile_img_card : {
            width: 96,
            height: 96,
            margin: 10,
        },
        errorMessage : {
            fontSize: 16,
            color: 'red',
            marginLeft: 15
        },
    })
    
    export default LoginForm;
```

I am new to react native, so it would be great if anyone could help me..